# Rails Home Index file not generating (or supporting files)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

When I run in terminal:
rails generate controller home index

This file, "app/views/home/index.html.erb." is not generated.

I did get what is below. . . .

=======

```
> 
> generate controller home index
>       create  
>       create  app/controllers
>       create  app/helpers
>       create  app/models
>       create  app/views/layouts
>       create  config/environments
>       create  config/initializers
>       create  config/locales
>       create  db
>       create  doc
>       create  lib
>       create  lib/tasks
>       create  log
>       create  public/images
>       create  public/javascripts
>       create  public/stylesheets
>       create  script/performance
>       create  test/fixtures
>       create  test/functional
>       create  test/integration
>       create  test/performance
>       create  test/unit
>       create  vendor
>       create  vendor/plugins
>       create  tmp/sessions
>       create  tmp/sockets
>       create  tmp/cache
>       create  tmp/pids
>       create  Rakefile
>       create  README
>       create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
>       create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
>       create  config/database.yml
>       create  config/routes.rb
>       create  config/locales/en.yml
>       create  db/seeds.rb
>       create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
>       create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
>       create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
>       create  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
>       create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
>       create  config/environment.rb
>       create  config/boot.rb
>       create  config/environments/production.rb
>       create  config/environments/development.rb
>       create  config/environments/test.rb
>       create  script/about
>       create  script/console
>       create  script/dbconsole
>       create  script/destroy
>       create  script/generate
>       create  script/runner
>       create  script/server
>       create  script/plugin
>       create  script/performance/benchmarker
>       create  script/performance/profiler
>       create  test/test_helper.rb
>       create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
>       create  public/404.html
>       create  public/422.html
>       create  public/500.html
>       create  public/index.html
>       create  public/favicon.ico
>       create  public/robots.txt
>       create  public/images/rails.png
>       create  public/javascripts/prototype.js
>       create  public/javascripts/effects.js
>       create  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
>       create  public/javascripts/controls.js
>       create  public/javascripts/application.js
>       create  doc/README_FOR_APP
>       create  log/server.log
>       create  log/production.log
>       create  log/development.log
>       create  log/test.log
```

Comment: what is the output of `rails -v`

Comment: Ah, yes, he's probably still on Rails 2.3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Rails 2 you need launch

```
./script/generate controller home index
```

The rails generate command is only on Rails 3

Comment: Thank you shingara.  That worked.  SHOULD I UPGRADE to 3 do you think?

Comment: no, it's not mandatory. Rails 3 is really different to Rails 2.